# Ravendb and SQL Server in a transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ravendb

i want to write an insert/update/delete statement that will insert/update/delete into ravendb and sql server at the same time.I want to be consistent at my updates,inserts and deletes.

how is it possible ? should i use msdtc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always wrap your code in a `TransactionScope`.  Both RavenDB and SQL Server will pick  up on it.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    ... SQL Stuff ...

    ... Raven Stuff ...

    ts.Complete();
}
```

You should read [this](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/faq/working-with-dtc) and [this](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/advanced/transaction-support).

But you might get better results just working with RavenDB in your application and then replicating to SQL Server.  Read [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/sql-replication).